# when I committed my local changes to a new branch, pushed that branch, then switched branches, and switched back, all my file changes were lost

Tags: git, github

My workflow was as follows. I have a remote repo with only one branch (Master).

On my local repo, I have a file. I edited it. I then used `git checkout -b newbranchname` to create a new branch. I added my file to this new branch to stage for commit. I then committed this file. I then pushed this file using `git push -u origin newbranchname`. I went to my remote repo, and lo and behold, my new branch and my files were available for a pull request.

Then, on my local repo, I decided to use `git checkout master` to go back to my master branch. I then added, committed, and pushed a different file to my remote master branch. Then, I used `git checkout newbranchname` to go back to the branch I created. When I opened up the first file I pushed, all my edits were gone. On my remote repo, I can see all the changes I had pushed and pulled. But, I don't understand why all my local changes disappeared. Can someone please explain?

Edit: Adding output from `git reflog` to provide more context. Also 'zoom' is the new branch I created:

```
`brendathompson@Brendas-Air Coding % git reflog
71a7da2 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
71a7da2 (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{1}: commit: setting up site queries
cab9374 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from zoom to master
db8374a (origin/zoom, zoom) HEAD@{3}: commit: added zoom to map
cab9374 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to zoom
cab9374 HEAD@{5}: commit: added modal popup feature
0b51d5c HEAD@{6}: commit: added alert popup, deleted unecessary extra shape
8a0654f HEAD@{7}: commit: deleted unecessary background image code
a73475c HEAD@{8}: pull origin master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
4d9eb53 HEAD@{9}: commit: changed height and width in past map css
acbb2a7 HEAD@{10}: pull origin master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
8f5c8c0 HEAD@{11}: commit: edited height and width of image map
f02c46c HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from IMAGE-MAP-EDITS to master
dd534f9 (origin/IMAGE-MAP-EDITS, IMAGE-MAP-EDITS) HEAD@{13}: commit: added javascript to make map responsive successfully
2f5a2af HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from master to IMAGE-MAP-EDITS
f02c46c HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving from IMAGE-MAP-EDITS to master
2f5a2af HEAD@{16}: commit: added a more detailed title
92559fe HEAD@{17}: pull origin master: Fast-forward
a2e05cc HEAD@{18}: commit: changed title of image map
f02c46c HEAD@{19}: checkout: moving from master to IMAGE-MAP-EDITS
f02c46c HEAD@{20}: pull origin master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
6552161 HEAD@{21}: commit: removed unecessary lines from present_map.html`
```

Edit #2: Okay so it's possible that the reason I am not seeing what my file looked like when I committed changes on the new branch is that when I try to switch to the new branch, I never actually switched to the new branch because I get this error: 
`brendathompson@Brendas-Air Coding % git checkout zoom
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    present_map.html
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting`

But, I did commit my changes to the file on the new branch (zoom) because I can see the changes on my remote repo...

Edit #3: In response to the previous error message, I committed my changes on the html file which raised the error. But, I still get the same error when I try to checkout.

Edit #4: Other users have commented that the workflow I described here does not match what appears in the git reflog. First, I will note that I did some extra things after the commands I listed in my question (for example, I tried to resolve the issue by pulling from my remote repo), so those extra commands are not included in the commands listed in my question. Second, I listed the commands here exactly how they appeared in terminal -- since I didn't clear my terminal at all before I posted my question, I was able to list my commands exactly how I wrote them. So, I am not sure why the git reflog does not reflect my workflow. I can't remember now, because this was around 24hrs ago, but perhaps this is because I closed terminal, opened it again, did some things, and then called reflog (I don't know how reflog works, and I also can't remember if this is what I actually did).

Edit #5: To access the branch, I used `git stash save file` while on `master` branch, and then used `git checkout newbranchname`. This allowed me to access the branch and my file successfully.

Comment: Please add a bit more information with examples what you did exactly...  
Maybe you can also provide the output of `git reflog`?

Comment: Files should be there... but if you committed, check the reflog `git reflog`

Comment: take a hard cold look at the revisions and their relations in the branches... something like `git log --oneline --graph --all --decoration`.

Answer (score 0):

when you push your local changes to a new branch, this means that you already save them, so you must make a pull request from the interface GitHub or (merge request for GitLab users), then merge the new branch in the master branch

please check my answer here [Git: Merge local branch to remote branches A and B without inserting code from A into B/ B into A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431376/git-merge-local-branch-to-remote-branches-a-and-b-without-inserting-code-from-a/61445968#61445968)